# How to add a text message server to contacts

Tags: contacts, sms, stock-android

I work in a rather large company, and I'm a emergency first responder (basically: provide life-saving first-aid, fight small fires and ensure buildings are properly evacuated when necessary). The company alerts us in multiple ways, one being a text message to my mobile phone.

This text message is sent from a server, so there's no phone number associated with it. Instead, the message details say "From: CM Direct" (which I believe is our particular text service provider).

I would like to add a contact for text messages received this way, in order to give it a custom ringtone (something loud and separate from the rest, to indicate this is an emergency call), but within the messaging app I can find no way to do so. For normal text messages I have a menu with an "Add to Contacts" option, but this menu does not appear when viewing a text message from the server.

I'm using an Samsung Galaxy S5 mini with Android 4.4.2 (stock). Rooting is not an option (not allowed because it's a company phone).

Any ideas on how to get this working properly?